# find the series $\frac{z}{\mathrm{e}^z-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

How can I find the series corresponding to the function$$\frac{z}{\mathrm{e}^z-1}$$  By seeing answer given in book I came to know that series is like $1-\frac{1}{2}z+\frac{1}{6}\frac{z^2}{\mathrm{2!}}+\cdots$but how will I solve this, please help.

Thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Generating_function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the answer as given in your book:

We have

$$e^z-1=z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+o(z^3)$$
so
$$\frac{z}{\mathrm{e}^z-1}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{z}{2!}+\frac{z^2}{3!}+o(z^2)}$$
Moreover, we have
$$\frac{1}{1+u}=1-u+u^2+o(u^2)$$
so by taking $u=\frac{z}{2!}+\frac{z^2}{3!}$ we find
$$\frac{z}{\mathrm{e}^z-1}=1-\left(\frac{z}{2!}+\frac{z^2}{3!}\right)+\left(\frac{z}{2!}+\frac{z^2}{3!}\right)^2+o(z^2)=1-\frac{z}{2!}+\frac{1}{12}z^2+o(z^2)$$